# In Momentjs, how to parse dates sent from server built in Java?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

I get dates from server as a list, for example, `[2017,8,24,9,0]`. When I parse and localize them in `momentjs`, all the dates are one month ahead:  instead of `August`, I get `September`. In case of `[2017,8,31,9,0]`, I get `invalid date`.I think it is because `September` is not `31` days.

My question is how to parse dates such as `[2017,8,24,9,0]`, `[2017,8,29,20,0]`, and `[2017,8,31,9,0]` into `D.MMM [kl.] H:mm` format?

I understand that `JavaScript date` is `zero-indexed` while java date isn't. I have used `momentjs` `subtract()` method, but `[2017,8,31,9,0]` is still `invalid date`.

Comment: Months in JavaScript are zero-based; you'll have to subtract one.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: No, I mean literally *from the second number in the array*.  That is, *before* you give it to moment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, if the API is under your control, send a better format like a Unix timestamp or ISO 8601 string.

Answer (score 1):

That's a javascript issue. But is not a bug. In js dates, [months are zero based](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). It is, 0 = january, 1 = february, etc. To solve this you can subtract the month by 1.

```
var myServerDate = [2017,8,24,9,0];

myServerDate[1] = myServerDate[1] -1;
```

Then you can proceed with the parsing process.